# Won't dare to VS will dare not to

Tags: sentence-construction

> I won't dare to forget you going forward.
>
> I will dare not to forget you going forward.

I am not sure which one is correct. Basically, I want to express I dare not to forget you in the future. Which one is proper in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a pure grammar standpoint, the first option is correct.

However, from the usage standpoint, it seems like a foreign language idiom correctly translated into English. It sounds strange.

"Going forward" is mostly used in businesslike contexts—how we will do things in the future (at our company or in our society). Urban Dictionary even [describes it as a corporate buzzword](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=going%20forward). It certainly sounds strange in a romantic context.

Is the speaker afraid that his beloved will send assassins to kill him if he forgets her? If not, then there is no reason to use the word "dare". As discussed in the comments, I think that this is a case of trying to translate a foreign phrasal verb into English word-for-word. E. g. in English, there is a phrase "to pay someone a visit". No one is actually *paying* anyone money or anything. It is just "to visit" with some added flourish. This kind of flourish is rarely translatable into other languages.

So an English speaker would just say "I will never ever forget you". There is no special idiom here.

Comment: Thanks! It's a romantic context. How would you express this?

Comment: "I will never ever forget you." There is simply no reason for the word "dare" here. The emphasis is added by saying "never ever" instead of just "never". The sense of the future is being taken care of by "will" and "ever". I think that this is a case of there being a set phrase in Chinese that you are trying to translate. E. g., to explain, there is a phrase in English "to pay someone a visit". It means simply **to visit** someone; no one is actually _paying_ anyone. It would be absurd in my native language to say, word for word, "pay a visit", so I would just say "visit".